# Peak detection algorithm in matrix

Tags: algorithm, detection, noise, maxima

Consider a bidimensionnel matrix that represents a 2D signal `Z = s(X,Y)`. This signal has several gaussian peaks and a background gaussian noise. The following image gives an example of such a signal :

[image]

I would like to find an algorithm that finds these peaks given several inputs :

- A threshold (z-axis) below which the algorithm is not expected to find any peaks
- The minimum distance that must separates two peaks in order for the algorithm to account for two peaks instead of one (distance in both x and y directions)

I first thought using the function `findpeaks` provided by MATLAB. However, this function does not seem to provide support for matrices.

Comment: try this: `answer = Z - smooth(Z)`

Answer (score 0):

From [matlab](https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/219759-how-to-use-findpeaks-for-a-matrix-of-size-a) answers,
The findpeaks function will work, but you have to cycle through the rows:

```
M = randi(99, 4, 8);
for k1 = 1:size(M,1)
    [pks,loc] = findpeaks(M(k1,:));
    P{k1} = [pks; loc];
end
```

The cell array accounts for different numbers of peaks and locations in each row. You could use this to find peaks.
 
About

> I would like to find an algorithm that finds these peaks given several
>   inputs :
>
> A threshold (z-axis) below which the algorithm is not expected to find
>   any peaks The minimum distance that must separates two peaks in order
>   for the algorithm to account for two peaks instead of one (distance in
>   both x and y directions)

Not so sure.